# Windows mandatory access control: How to remove “mandatory level” label from the file?

Tags: operating-systems, windows, access-control, file-system, uac

1. How to remove "mandatory level" label from the file?

   I have two files, for the first one `icacls` returns

   ```
   Mandatory Label\Medium Mandatory Level:(NW)
   ```

   for the second `icacls` doesn't return anything (that means use "default")

   My problem is that

   ```
   icacls /setintegritylevel [(CI)(OI)]Level
   ```

   can only set level label, when I need to remove it..
2. What are other methods (GUI/utilities) to manipulate file's mandatory level labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  found this tool:

http://www.minasi.com/apps/

```
chml filename -rl
```

remove mandatory level